# Find whether this set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given the following set $W$, determine if it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ under the operations of addition and scalar multiplication defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$.
$$W=\left\{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3:5a_1^2-3a_2^2+6a_3^2=0 \right\}$$
That quadratic expression is giving me some trouble, because I don't know how to use it to verify the conditions for subspaces.
Can you give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: A good way to start is to try to add two generic elements of $W$. Does it look like that will again be an element of $W$? If not, then find a concrete example of $v, w \in W$ such that $v + w \notin W$.

Comment: So you're saying that first I should try guessing/finding two elements of $W$ such that they verify the expression, but their sum doesn't belong to $W$?

Comment: try to find for two arbitrary elements of $W$ what would it mean for their sum to be in $W$ and see if that holds in general for every two elements

Comment: Hint: find $z$ such that $a=(0, 1, z)$ is in $W$. Is $b=(0,-1,z)$ also in $W$? What about $a+b$?

Comment: @E23500: Yes, that is what I meant. A nice way to guess usually is to first write the general expression and see what you would need for the sum to be in $W$. (Usually, in the case of quadratic stuff, you will be quite lucky and most guesses would turn out to be good for a counterexample.)

Answer (score 0):

**By the definition of subspace**

> $0\in W$, which is of course true since the vector$(0,0,0)$satisfes the given equation.

> Next, it should be closed under vector addition. That is, given vector $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and vector $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ in $W$ , the vector $(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,a_3+b_3)$ should be in $W$.

That means $5(a_1+b_1)^2-3(a_2+b_2)^2+6(a_3+b_3)^2$ should be $0$ **is it?**

I hope you from here you have some idea weather it is a subspace or not.

If something is not true then you need to produce a counterexample

$v_1=(0,1,1/√2)$,$v_2=(0,2,√2)$